# Reading DBF file in java/selenium

Tags: java, database, selenium, foxpro

I'm trying to read a FoxPo .dbf file, but getting below error for line:

**while ((rowObjects = reader.nextRecord()) != null)**

ERROR:

> com.linuxense.javadbf.DBFException: Failed to parse Number: empty
>   String
>       at com.linuxense.javadbf.DBFReader.nextRecord(DBFReader.java:310)
>       at datamigration.DataMigration.main(DataMigration.java:34)

Your help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Below if my code:

---

```
package datamigration;

import java.io.*;
import com.linuxense.javadbf.*;

public class DataMigration {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {

            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("D:/projects/DataMigration/data/customer.dbf");

            DBFReader reader = new DBFReader(inputStream);

            reader.setCharactersetName("gbk");
            int numberOfFields = reader.getFieldCount();

            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFields; i++) {

                DBFField field = reader.getField(i);

                System.out.println(field.getName());
            }

            Object[] rowObjects;

            while ((rowObjects = reader.nextRecord()) != null) {

                for (int i = 0; i < rowObjects.length; i++) {

                    System.out.println(rowObjects[i]);
                }
            }
            inputStream.close();

        } catch (DBFException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Most probably (based on the exception message `Failed to parse Number: **empty String** at `) there is a date column without a value. What have you done to identify the failed record?

Comment: Thanks @SubOptimal for your feedback...I will check the same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the various 'finds' at:
    [Google Search Results for:  java connect to foxpro database](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&q=java%20connect%20to%20foxpro%20database&oq=java%20to%20vfp%20data&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.0i22i30k1l2.3307.8126.0.11031.16.16.0.0.0.0.155.2027.0j16.16.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.16.2022...0j46j0i131k1j0i46k1j0i10k1j0i13k1j0i13i30k1j0i13i10i30k1j0i8i13i30k1.0.iGU_MkKT0gE)

Comment: Thanks @Dhugalmac for your feedback...I will so the search. I'm still a Newbie to Selenium/Java...But will cope up soon...Thanks for you help